# Is this pseudo-shopping question acceptable here?

Tags: discussion

For a class, I am using CDT to write c code in Eclipse and am uploading the code to a Unix machine, where the teacher reviews the code.

I am looking for a plug-in that will highlight lines of code/comments that are longer than a certain number of characters so that the text does not auto-wrap in a ssh client.

Is this a suitable question to ask on p.se?

Comment: Thanks for asking :)  Perhaps you can explain though why you feel that this isn't quite a shopping style question?

Comment: That said, you are looking for something akin to checkstyle for c which leads to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93260/a-free-tool-to-check-c-c-source-code-against-a-set-of-coding-standards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without even discussing if it's a constructive question, it's off-topic here. Questions about programming tools belong on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). I'm not going to try to guess how the SO community will react to this, but it seems to be specific enough. Assuming searching your favorite search engine and/or the Eclipse Marketplace reveals nothing useful, it might be OK.